# Rails API Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to combine 2 models and sort them out and expose the result on my serializer.

so in my user controller I have

```
  #users_controller.rb

  def transactions
    @debit = current_user.debits.all
    @credit = current_user.credits.all
    @history = [@debit, @credit].flatten
    @sorted_history = @history.sort_by { |item| item.created_at.strftime('%m/%d/%y') }
    render json: UserTransactionSerializer.new(@sorted_history).call
  end
```

and on my serializer I have:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class UserTransactionSerializer < BaseSerializer
      def call
        {
          id: object.id,
          amount: object.amount,
          status: object.status,
          created_at: object.created_at.iso8601
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm getting this error bellow:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<Array:0x0055ce49b57b20>)
```

EDIT: Typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@sorted_history` is an array, but `UserTransactionSerializer` should be passed in an object.

So easy solution would be:

```
render json: @sorted_history.map{ |trans| UserTransactionSerializer.new(trans).call }
```

Answer (score 1):

`object` is an Array, so you have to iterate and return hash for each object in that Array.

```
def call
  object.map do |obj|
    {
      id: obj.id,
      amount: obj.amount,
      status: obj.status,
      created_at: obj.created_at.iso8601
    }
  end
end
```